# Hi, Im new, do I make a java program that allows me to loop a question?

Tags: java

Im trying to make a program that can do the following.

Select a number from one to nine or press e to exit program.

for example I choose number 1, It would make me a simple multiplication test like "1x1:"  up to "1x10:" if I choose two it would ask "2x1" up to 2x10" each question would loop up to 4 attempts if you get the wrong answer or move to the next question if you get it right. How do I make it loop and my if methods doesn't work. please help.

```
    System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 to 9 or please press E to exit");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char num = scanner.next().charAt(0);

     
   
    switch (num) {

        case '1':
       System.out.println("1x1");
             char ans;
            ans = scanner.next().charAt(0);
       
       if(ans!= '1')
       {
              System.out.println("1x1");
              
            ans = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            
           while(ans!= '1' || i<=5)
           System.out.println("Incorrect try again!");
            System.out.println("1x1:");
            
            ans = scanner.next().charAt(0);
       s--;
     i++;
       }
       
       else if (ans=='1')
       {
        System.out.println("1x2");
       }
           
       
       else if(ans=='e'){
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
        }
```

Comment: I suggest posting working code to increase your chances of getting responses.

Comment: Please include any error messages or problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's pretty clear how it works but if you have a question go ahead.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%d * %d = ", i, j));
                int response = scanner.nextInt();
                int fails = 1;

                while (response != i * j && fails < 4) {
                    fails++;
                    System.out.print(String.format("%d * %d = ", i, j));
                    response = scanner.nextInt();
                }

                if (fails == 4) {
                    System.out.println("You failed!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just assume when user enters any letter it should exit the program. But you can change it to `else if(num == 'e')` and only then `System.exit()`.

```
public class stackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 to 9 or exit : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char num = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        Boolean check = Character.isDigit(num);
         if(check) {
            int value=Character.getNumericValue(num); 
            for(int i=1 ; i<=10 ; i++){
                System.out.println(num + "x" + i);
                System.out.println("Your answer : ");
                int userAnw = scanner.nextInt();
                int attemp = 1;
                
                while(userAnw != value*i && attemp!=4) {
                    attemp++;
                    System.out.println("Answer Wrong!");
                    userAnw = scanner.nextInt();
                }
                if(userAnw!=value*i) System.out.println("Answer Wrong!");
                else System.out.println("Answer correct!");
            }
         }
         else System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for let me know : D will improve next time : D